# Virtual function declared in a derived class

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, inlining

Here I have declared another virtual function in Derived class.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    string s;
    public:
    A(const string& name) : s(name){}
     virtual void f1(){cout << "f1 of base class" << endl;};
};

class B : public A{
    string p;
    public:
    B(const string& name) : A(name){}
    virtual void f2(){cout << "virtual function of derived class" << endl;}
    void f1(){cout << "f1 of derived class";}
};

int main() {
    A* arr[] = {new A("John"),new B("Bob")};
    arr[0]->f1();
    arr[1]->f1();
    arr[1]->f2();
    return 0;
}
```

The function call  **arr[1]->f2()**  gives the error "***‘class A’ has no member named ‘f2’***".I am wondering why the _vptr points to the VTABLE of base class even when B is upcasted to A.

Also I wanted to know , is inlining virtual functions safe?

Comment: You explicitly say that your B is a A. Compiler trusts you.

Comment: *even when arr[1] is upcasted to B*, that is not true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because there *is* no such member. `virtual` functions take place from the class where they are declared first down through all derived classes. They do not get bubbled up. When the compiler looks at `arr[ i ]->f2()` it looks up the definition of `arr` for its type. `arr` has (static) type `A`. So, the compiler looks up `A`'s definition for a suitable definition of `f2` and doesn't find any. Hence the diagnostic.

`virtual` functions can be safely inlined. In fact, all in-class definitions are *implicitly* inlined by the compiler. So, your `A::f1` is already inlined.

Comment: +1: good answer. Also it is worth mentioning that you don't "inline" functions yourself, you mark them "inline" and then the compiler decides whether he wants to inline the function or not. `inline` is really just a hint to the compiler that the function might be a good candidate.

Comment: @ereOn: Well `inline` means much more than a hint.`inline` usually indicates to the implementation that inline substitution of the function body at the point of call is to be preferred to the usual function call mechanism. An implementation is not required to perform this inline substitution at the point of call; however, even if this inline substitution is omitted, the other rules(especially w.r.t One Definition Rule) for `inline` are followed.

Comment: @Als: I forgot the ODR indeed, and you are right that "hint" isn't probably the best word. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to call `f2()` on an `A*`, and `A` doesn't have `f2()` declared.

`virtual` means that the method, when called through a *pointer* to a base class (including the class of the object itself), is resolved at runtime, based on the vptr table of the object you're calling it on. It doesn't make the method visible in base classes.

Inlining virtual functions is very safe but you won't *necessarily* get the performance boost you're expecting from it. Inlining means that the function code is copy-pasted by the compiler at the point of call. [See The C++ Super-FAQ on inlining and why it's a pie in the sky](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions)

Inlining is a **compile** time concept. Virtual method calls, called on a pointer to a base class, are resolved at **runtime**.

I.e. the following call to a function that's virtual, can be inlined:

```
B myB("The B.");
b.f1(); // not virtual, might be inlined
```

Comment: The compiler can inline a virtual call. Also, just because a method is `virtual`, doesn't mean it's resolved at run-time. See my answer.

Comment: I'm not saying it can't inline a virtual call. But yes, I'll need to edit the bit about the call resolution.

Comment: Well, you're saying the call is resolved at runtime, which implies it isn't inlined (which would mean there's no call to speak of).

Comment: I've edited my answer. virtual function calls != call to a function declared as virtual.

Answer (score 2):

Easy first:

> Also I wanted to know , is inlining virtual functions safe?

Yes, virtual functions *can* be inlined, but polymorphism is guaranteed to always work.

For example:

```
B b;
b.f2();
```

*can* be resolved at compile time, without using the virtual table, because the compiler knows the object is of type `B`.

> I am wondering why the _vptr points to the VTABLE of base class even when arr[1] is upcasted to B.

It doesn't. It points to the virtual table of class `B`, but the compiler doesn't see it. The virtual table is an implementation detail. You're calling a function on an `A*`, so `B`'s methods aren't visible. In this simple example, it's easy, but how could, in general, the compiler tell that `arr[1]` is a pointer to a `B` in fact? That's the whole point of polymorphism, you abstract away the derived type.

What you can do is:

```
dynamic_cast<B*>(arr[1]) ? (dynamic_cast<B*>(arr[1]))->f2() : (void)0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about it this way. At compile time, the compile is completely oblivious of the actual type of the object that `arr[i]` is pointing to. That type only becomes known at runtime. So when you write something like this:

```
arr[i]->f2();
```

the compiler doesn't know what code to produce to make that call happen. What is f2? Is it the f2 that is declared in B? What if you also have a a subclass of A called C, which also has a virtual function named f2, and the object that arr[i] points to just happens to be of type C? We don't know.

You will immediately see that the only sane behavior in such case is to produce an error.

Answer (score 0):

`arr[1]` is of type `A*` which doesn't have a method called `f2`. You'd have to cast `arr[1]` to `B*`, but I don't think that's a good idea. Change your data structures instead.